# How do I synchronize my FireFox Bookmarks from my PC to both my android devices?

Tags: sync, bookmarks, firefox-for-android

My web browser is Firefox 11 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I have a lot of well organized bookmarks that I would like to synchronize with both my Android Devices (Galaxy 10.1 tab & Galaxy S Phone).  I want to maintain my PC as the book mark server.  I wasn't sure where to ask this question "Ask Ubuntu" or here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By far the easiest way to do this is to use Firefox as your web browser everywhere, and then use Firefox's built in sync functionality. This will (optionally) sync not just your Bookmarks, but also your History, your Saved Passwords and your Preferences, and let you see the recent tabs you've had open on different machines.

Start by installing [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox), then on your PC go into Firefox's Options, click the Sync tab and run through the wizard to set up sync and the encryption key.

Then open Firefox on your Android device and you should see a prominent option to set up sync that will involve copying a short authentication code between your phone and PC copies of Firefox. After that it will start pulling all of the info down from your PC to your phone (you may want to make sure you're on wifi for this first sync).

For a clearer guide, with pictures, see this page on the Mozilla support site [How do I sync Firefox between my desktop and mobile?](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/sync-firefox-between-desktop-and-mobile)